# Sekering database sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me...I want to delete row from table in database with condition..

Comment: The documentation is quite clear https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html, Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question and not add more details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

delete from ENTERYOURTABLENAMEHERE
where ENTERCONDITIONHERE

e.g. 
delete from employeestable
where age < 30

delete from employeestable
where name = 'anonymous'

Comment: I have tabel A, B and , C . Position on tabel C .how to if we want to delete the rows where the row is not in table A and not in table B

Comment: delete from tableC where value not in (select value from tableA) and value not in (select value from tableB)

Comment: DELETE from biblio_status_hist where value not in (SELECT value from biblio) and value not in (SELECT value from member)

Please help me.. not working..

Comment: can you please give me the table names you're working with and the column names for each table?

Comment: Table 1. Biblio_status_hist
Table 2. Member
Tabel 3. Biblio
And premery key  from tabel table 1. Id
Table 2. Mbrid
Table 3. Bibid

In table 1.. there isi "bibid" and "..mbrid"...

Please help